# It is necessary to solve the problem with exponentiation

Tags: python, exponentiation

I need to solve a problem in a Python milking beginners course.

> You are offered a one-time payment of $1,000,000 or 1 cent, which doubles every day for 30 days (the amount received doubles every day).
>
> Write a program to calculate the amount obtained by doubling to determine in which case the amount is greater.

My attempts:

```
i = 0.01
for i in range(31):
  day = i
  day_1 = day * (2 ** 2)
  print(i)
```

I don't know how to tell the program to calculate the amount for each day until the 30th, except to specify it for each day separately - but then you get a very long code (one line for each day), I think there should be a command that does it faster.

```
i = 0.01
for i in range(31):
  day = i
  day_1 = day * (2 ** 2)
  
  
  print(i)
```

Comment: 1+2+4+8+...+2^29 = 2^30 - 1, so `total = 2**30 - 1` computes the total amount received in the doubling case (in cents). Now 2**10 = 1024 > 1000, so total is at least 1000*1000*1000=1000 million cents = 10 million dollars, so it's much better to take the doubling amount.

Comment: If you are supposed to "solve the problem with exponentiation" why are you doing it by a loop? Just ```print( 0.01 * ( 2 ** 30 - 1 ), "dollars" )```. (But I prefer Paul Hankin's quick estimate.) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfH8lQwBHfQ

Comment: This code also didn’t work in course program. Only code from  “Martin” - works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
start = 0.01
temp = start

for i in range(0, 30):
  temp = temp*2

print(temp)
```

This code will have a start value, and set a temp variables value to the start. For every day in the 30 days, it will double the value in the temp value, and then print the final total amount when done.

Answer (score -1):

first I dont think using i as your starting value is not a good move since its often used as iterator for loops. Try this instead:

```
value = 0.01
step = 1
while step < 30:
 value = value * 2
 step = step + 1
 print(value)
```

Comment: It’s didn’t work. I checked it in my coursework

Comment: @Jantek Has my solution worked for you?

Comment: what exactly didnt work?

Comment: Your solution gives something like this: 41943.04

83886.08

167772.16

335544.32

671088.64

1342177.28

2684354.56

5368709.12. And the right answer must be : 10737418.24 - only one number.